# adding a key for geom_line to legend from geom_area

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame, where I am talking about different flows of water at a dam (water units are kcfs—1000 cubic feet per second—if anyone is interested)

Call it df4plot

```
    date         kcfs    Flowtype
    10/1/2010        50     Power
    10/1/2010        10     Spill_Overgen
    10/1/2010         8         Spill_Force
    10/2/2010        52     Power
    10/2/2010         7     Spill_Overgen
    10/2/2010        10     Spill_Force
```

(there are 3x365 rows in the data frame)

So what I want to do is make an aggregated area graph that shows each of  these flows

```
p <- ggplot(data = df4plot, aes(date,kcfs)) +
geom_area(aes(colour = Flowtype, fill=Flowtype), position = “stack”)
```

I want to control the colors used, so I added

```
plot_colors_aggregate <- c("forestgreen","lightsalmon","dodgerblue")
p <- p +
scale_color_manual(values = plot_colors_aggregate) +
scale_fill_manual(values = plot_colors_aggregate)
```

Now I want to add a dashed line, showing the maximum turbine capacity—the flow limits for power generation—that vary by month.  I have a separate dataframe for this (365 rows long), df4FGline

```
    Date    FGlimit
    10/1/2010   52
    10/2/2010   52
     …
    11/1/2010   60
    11/2/2010   60
    ...
    Etc
```

So now I have

```
p <- p + 
geom_line(data = df4FGline, aes(x=date,y=FGlimit), colour = “darkblue”, linetype = “dashed”)

p
```

The legend is currently just the three blocks for the three types of Flowtype.  I’d like to add the dashed line for the flow gate limits to the bottom, but I can’t get it to show up there.

It is probably related to my incomplete understanding of aes (help(aes) is AMAZINGLY unhelpful).

I’ve tried something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9915824/how-can-i-make-a-legend-in-ggplot2-with-one-point-entry-and-one-line-entry)  and something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027016/missing-legend-with-ggplot2-and-geom-line?rq=1), but since I’m only trying to add 1 line to a pre-existing legend, maybe?, this is not working for me.

I tried adding “legend = TRUE” inside the parentheses for the geom_line, but it put a dashed line inside each color box in the legend, AND created a 4th entry for the legend, but offset from the rest of the legend (below and to the right)... ARG!

I swear I have the book on order... any help you can share so that I understand this aesthetic thing and how it relates to the legend a little better, I'd be extremely grateful.

*edited for typo*

Comment: Here's a hint: ggplot will automatically create a legend if you _map_ an aesthetic (inside of `aes()`), but not if you _set_ an aesthetic.

Comment: But aren't both of my geoms doing this mapping thing, using aes()?  Can you point me to anywhere I can read about this difference between _mapping_ and _setting_ I'd be grateful.

Comment: Linetype is set outside of aes() in geom_line.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help on this I appreciate it.

So _set_ is outside of aes() but inside geom_line(); _map_ is inside of aes(). when I move "linetype = 'dashed'" into aes()--when I _map_ it--my line is no longer dashed, but now I have a legend entry. If I have linetype = "dashed" in both locations, it goes back to my first version, with no legend entry. Is there a way to get _both_ a legend entry _and_ a dashed line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10,y = 1:10)
ggplot(df,aes(x = x,y = y)) + 
   geom_line(aes(linetype = "dashed")) + 
   scale_linetype_manual(name = "Linetype",values = "dashed")
```

Comment: @user156870 Just so you know, the reason I didn't put more time into your question is that your example code wasn't terribly reproducible. Notice that my example code above can simply be copy+pasted and run in an R session. Not so with your code, and that usually makes it much more difficult to help.