# Is it possible to create 3 series (2 lines and one point) faceted plot in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to write a code that I wrote with a basic graphics package in R to ggplot.

The graph I obtained using the basic graphics package is as follows:

[image: Example image containing six graphs]

I was wondering whether this type of graph is possible to create in ggplot2. I think we could create this kind of graph by using panels but I was wondering is it possible to use faceting for this kind of plot. The major difficulty I encountered is that maximum and minimum have common lengths whereas the observed data is not continuous data and the interval is quite different.

Any thoughts on arranging the data for this type of plot would be very helpful. Thank you so much.

Comment: This is simple to produce in ggplot with different layers and facets. Post some sample data and your best attempt at producing a ggplot, and somebody can surely help.

Comment: I have one question. In the above figure, the legend is not showing properly. Maximum and minimum should not have point there. Is it possible to remove the points from maximum and minimum in above figure ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jdbaba,

From your comments, you mentioned that you'd like for the `geom_point` to have just the `.` in the legend. This is a feature that is yet to be implemented to be used directly in `ggplot2` (if I am right). However, there's a fix/work-around that is given by `@Aniko` in [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253179/using-ggplot2-how-can-i-represent-a-dot-and-a-line-in-the-legend). Its a bit tricky but brilliant! And it works great. Here's a version that I tried out. Hope it is what you expected.

```
# bind both your data.frames
df <- rbind(tempcal, tempobs)

p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = time, y = data, colour = group1, 
                 linetype = group1, shape = group1))
p <- p + geom_line() + geom_point()
p <- p + scale_shape_manual("", values=c(NA, NA, 19))
p <- p + scale_linetype_manual("", values=c(1,1,0))
p <- p + scale_colour_manual("", values=c("#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00"))
p <- p + facet_wrap(~ id, ncol = 1)
p
```

The idea is to first create a plot with all *necessary* attributes set in the aesthetics section, plot what you want and then change settings manually later using `scale_._manual`. You can `unset` lines by a `0` in `scale_linetype_manual` for example. Similarly you can `unset` points for lines using `NA` in `scale_shape_manual`. Here, the first two values are for `group1=maximum and minimum` and the last is for `observed`. So, we set `NA` to the first two for `maximum` and `minimum` and set `0` to `linetype` for `observed`.

And this is the plot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Solution found:**
Thanks to Arun and Andrie

Just in case somebody needs the solution of this sort of problem.

The code I used was as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
tempcal <-  read.csv("temp data ggplot.csv",header=T, sep=",")
tempobs <- read.csv("temp data observed ggplot.csv",header=T, sep=",")
p <- ggplot(tempcal,aes(x=time,y=data))+geom_line(aes(x=time,y=data,color=group1))+geom_point(data=tempobs,aes(x=time,y=data,colour=group1))+facet_wrap(~id)
p
```

The dataset used were https://www.dropbox.com/s/95sdo0n3gvk71o7/temp%20data%20observed%20ggplot.csv

https://www.dropbox.com/s/4opftofvvsueh5c/temp%20data%20ggplot.csv

The plot obtained was as follows:

[image]

Jdbaba